# js Никак не могу настроить бота discord на выдачу роли новым участникам

Tags: javascript, node.js, бот, discord

Сам занимаюсь этим недавно, вот что-то написал... Облазил все документации, четкого решения так и не нашёл.

```js
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', (guildMember) => {
    guildMember.addRole(guildMember.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Guest"));
});
```

Выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
        guildMember.addRole(guildMember.guild.roles.get(role => role.name === "Guest"));
                                                    ^
TypeError: guildMember.guild.roles.bet is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

Судя по данной ошибке `TypeError: guildMember.guild.roles.bet is not a function`, скорее всего Вы ошиблись в написании функции.

Допустим, что Вы не ошиблись. Тогда попробуйте данный код (Версия discord.js - `12.3.1`):

```js
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', async (guildMember) => {
    // await делаю, чтобы было удобнее, и Вам впредь рекомендую всегда делать ожидание завершения действия
    // Также, никогда не делайте выдачу роли по имени, ведь имя может смениться. Для этого существует ID роли (правый клик по роли в дискорде > Скопировать ID, отмечу, что для этого Вы должны включить функции для разработчиков в настройках дискорда)
    await guildMember.roles.add('ID Роли');
});
```

Comment: Вопрос решил самостоятельно ``bot.on('guildMemberAdd', (guildMember) => {
 console.log('Подключился');
 guildMember.roles.add(guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Guest"));
 console.log(`Выдал роль человеку ${guildMember}`);
});``